# Modelling cell division in blender

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, scripting, animation-nodes

I want to make an animation where a simple cell divides into two but how could I animate that Morphy or glooby division (organic not simple cutting into two halves or duplicating like copy and paste)? I have seen a lot of tutorials using metal balls but they are too rigid and cannot be modified to a great extent like meshes.

Edit like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvgEaDVCKfA&feature=youtu.be#t=1m52s

Comment: @JachymMichal I am not asking about how to make a cell I am asking about how to make the glooby and morphy-like division

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In that case I'd also stick to metaballs, but I'm in no way expert on this. Good luck.

Comment: you should picture of what you want, is it realistic or not, etc...

Comment: you linked to a 4:50 video, could you [edit] your answer to point out where does the animation you want occurs?

Comment: The part where carcinogenic cells start division at 1:52

Comment: Yes metaballs are perfect for this purpose

Answer (score 3):

Here may be an alternative to Metaballs, I remember seeing something similar done with 3DS Maxs symmetry modifier so I attempted to try something with Blenders mirror modifier in combination with other modifiers.

[image]

[image: ball split gif]

On your mesh that you want to split go into edit mode and select some vertices where you want there to be tension during the animation and apply a hook modifier then a mirror modifier (use a empty for your mirror modifier origin) and then apply some smooth and sub D modifiers towards the end. Maybe the animation can be baked and then soft body dynamics could be applied but I've never tried that though, just a thought.

[image: ball split using modifiers]

Comment: Good answer but the original problem persists because we want the new meshes not to mix with each other but unfortunately they will mix again after separation

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish sounds like it would require multiple techniques and hacks to get the correct end result, or you made need to look into a more procedural approach. Metaballs is probably your best option if this is for  some sort of medical animation. Maybe check out the Animation Nodes add-on

Comment: how did you animate it? i cannot recreate the effect unless in edit mode

Comment: The empty connected to the hook modifier is keyframed to help create the pull apart effect.

Answer (score 1):

As Jachym says, you should use metaballs.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to create a metaball, call it for example A. Give it a material with a bit of noise. To increase its resolution, decrease the *Resolution* value in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Metaball*. Duplicate it, it will be called A.001, as you can see A.001 will merge with A.

[image]

- If you want to make metaballs that won't merge with others, just duplicate a metaball and give it a different prefix, like for example "B" (but don't give it any suffix). Duplicate B. B and its copies won't merge with A and its copies, it will only merge with B and its copies.

[image]

- In your video, the cells behave a bit like softbodies, as I don't see how you could mix metaballs and softbodies, what you could do to fake this effect is gather 3 metaballs, keep them together as if they were one object and make them bounce a bit. Maybe someone will have a better solution...

[image]

Comment: Very good answer but I want also the formed or new cell (metaball that appears after merging) not to mix or merge with the original cell after separation.

Comment: mmh you're right, not easy

Comment: anyway you have teached me a new blender trick. I think the answer may involve some python codes.However, as a trial you can change the stiffness of the metaball from active element settings and this might partially solve the problem but still the metaballs will not be able to bounce over each other or stand on each other.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been wondering how to create an extra set of Metaballs that would not merge with others in the same scene.